# Peak delation in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this numpy array:

```
A = [ 0.31  0.96  1.66  1.98  2.19  2.67  3.04  3.13  2.94  2.79  2.88  2.58 2.25  2.28  2.16  1.88  1.38  0.78  0.35]

AL = np.asarray(A)
AL = A.astype(float)
```

I've successfully calculated the Standard Deviation and Shannon Entropy like this:

```
std=np.std(AL, axis=0)
print "STD: ",str(std)
AL /= AL.sum()
S=-np.sum(AL * (np.log2(AL)))
print "ShaEn: ", str(S)
```

Does anybody know about Peak Dilation and how would it be calculated in python?

Comment: Do you have the definition or formula of "Peak Dilation"?

Comment: I believe the concept is decribed here, but honestly I am unable to understand it and I know nobody who knows about it. https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Laith_Sultan2/publication/301676608_Feed-forward_active_contour_analysis_for_improved_brachial_artery_reactivity_testing/links/5721260408ae5454b23100b8/Feed-forward-active-contour-analysis-for-improved-brachial-artery-reactivity-testing.pdf?origin=publication_detail

Comment: The "dilation" in the research seems to mean the physical dilation of *blood vessel*. Perhaps "Peak dilation" is simply the maximum of the numbers?

Comment: You must be asking the wrong people. This is a programming site, not a biology site.

Comment: @DYZ do you know any site where I can ask this type of questions? Thanks man.

Comment: Turns out it is the maximum in the array. Thanks @kennytm
http://www.answers.com/Q/Is_there_a_difference_between_the_Crest_and_the_Peak_Dilation_of_Sinusoidal_Signal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be the maximum in the array

```
Maxi=np.max(A, axis=0)
print "Max: ",str(Maxi)
```